# Cannot locate config in PulseAudio set up, Sound not working in Ubuntu 22.04 VM in Hyper V

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, hyper-v

Trying to get sound on Ubuntu 22.04 VM in Hyper V.

Following this guide:
https://techbloggingfool.com/2020/12/26/deploy-a-linux-vm-on-hyper-v-with-sound-20-04-edition/

have been able to navigate all steps except for sudo ./configure in 'pulseaudio-15.99.1+dfsg1' which is created in a previous step with sudo apt source pulseaudio

Error reads sudo: ./configure: command not found (because well it isn't there.)

I assume this is due to version 15.99.1 being different to the version the tutorial is based on (13.99 I think) but I cannot find any documentation for what the config file is.

anyone who knows the next step here would be greatly appreciated, I am on day 2 of trying to get this working lol.

-- What I have tried:

git clone https://github.com/neutrinolabs/pulseaudio-module-xrdp.git contains script folders that could act as config but don't seem to work.

Tried the bootstrap files in the same directory which ran but stopped on the make instruction later.

have confirmed all dependencies listed on github install guide
apt install build-essential dpkg-dev libpulse-dev git autoconf libtool

Tried setting up via gui with apt install pavucontrol which only gave "Dummy Output", same as settings.

Same problem exists in optimized Ubuntu 22.04 from Hyper V quick set up gallery.